# Android programming to convert a string array to double array

Tags: android

I need to convert a string array to double array in android. But my app is not getting executed on my device. It shows unfortunately stopped.Following is my code:

```
String dataa="0.121 0.547 0.875 0.245";                                    
String delimiter = " ";

String spectrainstring[] = dataa.split(delimiter);

int size = spectrainstring.length;

double[] spectraldata={0.0};

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)    
{   
    spectraldata[i]=Double.parseDouble(spectrainstring[i].toString());     
}
```

Comment: Please review the code you posted and make sure it is exactly what you are executing on your local machine. It would also be very nice if you showed us the logcat output as that will tell us what the problem is and what line of code it starts from.

Comment: At first glance my guess is that it's an IndexOutOfBounds issue because the double array you are trying to populate has only a length of 1 but you loop until `size` which in this case is 4.

Comment: Also any reason not to use a Scanner class?

Answer (score 1):

```
String dataa = "0.121 0.547 0.875 0.245";
String delimiter = " ";

String spectrainstring[] = dataa.split(delimiter);

int size = spectrainstring.length;

double[] spectraldata = new double[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    spectraldata[i] = Double.parseDouble(spectrainstring[i].toString());
    System.out.println(spectraldata[i]);
}
```

Comment: Important line change is double[] spectraldata = new double[size];

Comment: Actually sir, I am getting error in parsing the string variable to double. When I comment this line, the other code gets executed.

Comment: This line double[] spectraldata = {0.0}; gives you java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How it's working for you as there are 4 double values?

Comment: I have made a change there as: double[] spectraldata = new double[size];